# Why does eslint warn me of this piece of code while TypeScript doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Hello fellow developers.

Got a quick question, appreciate it if someone could help me out.
I have this snippet of code in my project.

```
useEffect(() => {

        const authUser = async () => {
            try {
                const loggedInUser = await Api.authenticateUser();
                context.setUser(loggedInUser);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                navigate(/login);
            }
        };
        authUser();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
```

And eslint warns me that I should put navigate and context in the dependency array.
I can do this to get the eslint error away, but then the page will re-render indefinitely, so I disabled eslint for that line.
If I remove the dependency array then I get indefinite re-rendering again, so no matter what I do I am screwed.
Is this snippet bad practice? TypeScript doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

Thanks guys.

I have tried to remove the dependency array, and add the dependencies but both result in a re-rendering chaos.

Comment: `Why does eslint warn me of this piece of code while TypeScript doesn't?` Because this problem has nothing to do with types. Its _valid_ (Typescript) code.

Comment: So eslint interferes with legitimate code structure/syntax? Hmm... I must have misunderstood the purpose of eslint.

Comment: `So eslint interferes with legitimate code structure/syntax?` Thats its job, yes. A linter helps finding common problems in _valid_ code. Think of `if(i = 4)`. Its valid code, it assigns `4` to `i` and then checks the truthiness value of `i` which is always true. Its __valid__ and runs, but its probably not what the programmer intended. _Thats_ what linters are for.